# Messed up my PATH environment variable and can't login to desktop

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables, gnome-session

To get an maven environment variable to run, I tried several options. Basically, I followed some options from [Ubuntu Community Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), such as `~/.pam_environment`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and I don't really know anymore. Within them I exported sth like `export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:$PATH` (I'm being so unconcrete because I cannot look it up).

Afterwards, I did run `gnome-session-quit` and my machine got stuck.

So after hard restart I try to login again, but I'm not able to do that: I see my username, enter the password, hit enter, screen turns black and after 2 seconds I'm back at the login screen.

So, that very strange and worrying. Next step: Login via tty (`Strg + ALT + F3`). Within there I can login, but can not do much. I thought about sth like [removing .Xauthority file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215585/unable-to-login-after-killing-gnome-session). But whatever I do: `The command could not be located because '\bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.` I think, altogether thats alarming and I'm getting really nervous.

Executing `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH` seems to work and `echo $PATH`gives an output starting with `/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/home/user/Documents/.../esper/examples/transaction/etc:/home/user/anaconda3/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin` but does not really help.

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 on an Lenovo G50-70.

Can you help me accessing my desktop again and/or fixing my PATH issue?

Comment: can you update your question with the output from `echo $PATH`? The snippet you provided is incomplete. Adding `/usr/bin` to the PATH a second time is futile.

Comment: Yeah, of course. See above.

Comment: Try this: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:$PATH` and let me know if you can use the system normally.

Comment: That helps. I'm now able to use commands like `ll`, `nano` again. That's definitely going in the right direction.

Comment: Can you run `gedit`?

Comment: `gedit`leads to `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused \n (gedit:2557): Gtk-WARNING **: ...: cannot open display:`

Comment: Are you logged into  console / terminal mode then? ie not desktop GUI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87263/discussion-between-so-s-and-wineunuuchs2unix).

Comment: Sometimes when X cannot load my desktop, I find useful error messages in `~/.xsession-errors`

Answer (score 4):

Enter this command:

```
nano /etc/environment
```

Make the first line read:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:"
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Type `reboot` to restart your computer.

Comment: I tried this approach. Nevertheless, after reboot I got the same problem. Therefore, I logged in via tty again. Within there I had to run `PATH=/usr/...` again, to be able to use the terminal. The changes made to `/etc/environment` are still there.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed the problem. Therefore, I did two things: Removing all previously made changes to any file that stores environment variables. Then I was able to login again ;). During login a message popped up pointing to an error in my `/home/user/.profile`. Within there I must have somehow uncommented the first line, whích caused the error. 
Thank you very much @WinEunuuchs2Unic, you have been very helpful at solving this issue!

Comment: @SoS You're most welcome. I actually screwed up my own `/etc/environment` during this exercise but was able to rebuild it from our message history. Just now I added it to my daily backup though :)

Answer (score 3):

Perform below steps. It will solve your issue permanently.

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + F3
2. Enter your username.
3. Enter your password.
4. Run these commands.

   ```
   echo $PATH
   export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
   source ~/.bashrc 
   export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
   source ~/.profile
   export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" 
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```
5. It will open a file and keep only the first line `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"` and remove other path or environment variable if any.
6. Press Ctrl + X (to save the file).
7. Press Y (to confirm save changes).
8. Press Enter to save (to confirm changes in the current file).
9. Reboot with `sudo reboot`

Comment: What is the point of re-sourcing `.bashrc` and `.profile` even when no modifications were made? `export` sets the environment variable for current shell which on termination/closure of shell would vanish. The `export PATH....` commands in your answer **are identical**. If you're modifying `/etc/environment`, there's no need to *`export`*.