# Messed up my PATH, now i can't login

Tags: login

So I messed up my `$PATH` when trying to put BLAST into my `/etc/enviroment`. Now I can't log in to Ubuntu (version 20.04), each time I attempt a login it just loads a couple of seconds and then sends me back to the login screen. I have tried launching the terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and ran `sudo nano /etc/enviroment` to write the following, according to an older an similar [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102970/messed-up-my-path-environment-variable-and-cant-login-to-desktop) and from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979512/unable-to-login-to-ubuntu-running-on-virtualbox):

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:"
```

Yet this does nothing for me and the problem persists.

I did change the `$PATH` within `.profile` as well but I managed to remove these changes using vim inside the Terminal.

Error messages:

[image: Error message]

[image: echo $PATH]

Comment: Your terminal output shows that you are logged in. Maybe you cannot open a graphical environment? Try the command `startx`

Comment: Did you edit `/etc/enviroment`? It should be `/etc/environment` instead. Verify the spellings.

Comment: Yes, it was the graphical environment that wasn't working. 

Also, it would appear that I am quite indeed dumb..... using vim and removing the changes I made in /etc/environment solved the problem. Thank you Kulfy! That misspelling cost me almost an entire workday :( 

And thank you for the reply Archisman Panigrahi!

You both are wonderful people!